# linear separability of points in a plane

Tags: c++

I am creating an algorithm using c++.
I have a plane of 320*240 pixels and a line (y=ax + b) that separates the plane in 2 polygons.
Given these information I would like to ask, if it is possible to know, in which of the 2 polygons, a new pixel(x,y) belongs to.

Answer (score 4):

you can separate according to if

```
 y<ax+b or y>ax+b
```